# Exceed AREF voltage

Tags: power

Let's say that I use a 5V Arduino board, and I set AREF to 3V, thus 0-3V equals to 0-1023 of the analog inputs.

If I exceed the AREF voltage, powering an analog pin with 4V, could that damage the analog input pin? If not, what would be the reading?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reading would saturate at 1023 when the voltage on the input pin exceeds AREF.

The datasheet (for the ATmega328P) states as absolute maximum rating for the "Voltage on any Pin except -RESET with respect to Ground" V<sub>CC</sub> + 0.5 V. So applying 4 V to AREF for a 5 V Arduino board should not (necessarily) damage the ATmega. (But you also won't be able to extend the 10-bit resolution range, if that is what you're after...)

In short, choose the reference voltage above the maximum expected voltage.

Comment: ... should not **(necessarily)** damage the ATmega. Could you clarify the "necessarily" statement?

Comment: Yes: I don't think it would do damage, but I won't give you a guarantee :) When you apply 4 V you are well inside the absolute maximum rating (which would be 5.5 V) but also quite a bit above the max value given under ADC Characteristics (which is VREF, i.e. 3 V).